# App crashes and Program receives error signal SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: [LeavesCache setDataSource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7db1f30

Added Exception breakpoint and found that problem is at this line

```
  pageCache = [[LeavesCache alloc] initWithPageSize:self.bounds.size];

 - (void) initialize {
backgroundRendering = NO;
pageCache = [[LeavesCache alloc] initWithPageSize:self.bounds.size];
   }



- (id) initWithPageSize:(CGSize)aPageSize
 {
if (self = [super init]) {
    pageSize = aPageSize;
    pageCache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
return self;
}


- (void) setDataSource:(id<LeavesViewDataSource>)value {
pageCache.dataSource = value;
 }
```

Have no idea how to fix this if some one can help me in this

Comment: Make sure you have implemented the LeavesViewDataSource protocol?

Comment: LeavesViewDataSource protocol are already present in LeavesView and Leaves Cache files

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using [this library][1], but it doesn't match up with what you've posted. Because the `LeavesCache` library on GitHub has no `setDataSource` method in the code - it's property declared instead. Have you made modifications to the source? Somebody has, because you seem to be setting the `pageCache` instance variable in one method to a `NSMutableDictionary`, and in another to a `LeavesCache` object.

Is there any particular reason why you're using this library? As far as I can tell, it hasn't been updated for three years, and iOS has supported iBooks like page turning interface since iOS 5 natively, using the `UIPageViewController` class.

Comment: You are right setDataSource method is in LeavesView  not in LeavesCache. I didnot made any changes to the code. I m using it as it is. Only difference is that in my case there is no navigationcontroller. But that should not make any difference if i m not wrong.

Comment: Using arc though if that makes difference in leaves caching